# (Python) correct use of greenlets

Tags: python, python-2.7, gevent

I have a remotely installed BeagleBone Black that needs to control a measurement device, a pan/tilt head, upload measured data, host a telnet server,...
I'm using Python 2.7
This is the first project in which I need to program, so a lot of questions come up.
I'd mostly like to know if what I'm doing is a reasonable way of handling what I need and why certain things don't do what I think.

Certain modules need to work together and share data. Best example is the telnet module, when the telnet user requests the position of the pan/tilt head.

As I understand it, the server is blocking the program, so I use gevent/Greenlets to run it from the "main" script.
Stripped down versions:

### teln module

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()  # patch functions to use gevent
import gevent
import gevent.server
from telnetsrv.green import TelnetHandler, command

__all__ = ["MyTelnetHandler", "start_server"]  # used when module is loaded as "from teln import *"

class MyTelnetHandler(TelnetHandler):
    """Telnet implementation."""

    def writeerror(self, text):
        """Write errors in red, preceded by 'ERROR: '."""
        TelnetHandler.writeerror(self, "\n\x1b[31;5;1mERROR: {}\x1b[0m\n".format(text))

    @command(["exit", "logout", "quit"], hidden=True)
    def dummy(self, params):
        """Disables these commands and get them out of the "help" listing."""
        pass

def start_server():
    """Server constructor, starts server."""
    server = gevent.server.StreamServer(("", 2323), MyTelnetHandler.streamserver_handle)
    print("server created")
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        server.close()
        print("server finished")



"""Main loop"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

### Main script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()  # patch functions to gevent versions
import gevent
from gevent import Greenlet
import teln  # telnet handler
from time import sleep
from sys import exit

"""Main loop"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread_telnet = Greenlet(teln.start_server)
    print("greenlet created")
    thread_telnet.start()
    print("started")
    sleep(10)
    print("done sleeping")
    i = 1
    try:
        while not thread_telnet.ready():
            print("loop running ({:03d})".format(i))
            i += 1
            sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("interrupted")
        thread_telnet.kill()
        print("killed")
        exit()
```

The final main loop would need to run much more functions.

questions:

1. Is this a reasonable way of running processes/functions at the same time?
2. How do I get a function in the telnet module to call functions from a third module, controlling the head?
3. How do I make sure that the head isn't being controlled by the telnet module as well as the main script (which runs some kind of schedule)?
4. In the "def start_server()" function in teln module, two print commands are called when starting and stopping the server. I do not see these appearing in the terminal. What could be happening?
5. When I open a telnet session from a remote machine, and then close it, I get the following output (program keeps running):

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 536, in run
       result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telnetsrv/telnetsrvlib.py", line 815, in inputcooker
       c = self._inputcooker_getc()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telnetsrv/telnetsrvlib.py", line 776, in _inputcooker_getc
       ret = self.sock.recv(20)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/_socket2.py", line 283, in recv
       self._wait(self._read_event)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/_socket2.py", line 182, in _wait
       self.hub.wait(watcher)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 651, in wait
       result = waiter.get()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 898, in get
       return self.hub.switch()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 630, in switch
       return RawGreenlet.switch(self)
   cancel_wait_ex: [Errno 9] File descriptor was closed in another greenlet
   Fri Sep 22 09:31:12 2017 <Greenlet at 0xb6987bc0L: <bound method MyTelnetHandler.inputcooker of <teln.MyTelnetHandler instance at 0xb69a1c38>>> failed with cancel_wait_ex
   ```

While trying out different things to get to understand how greenlets work, I have received similar ("cancel_wait_ex: [Errno 9] File descriptor was closed in another greenlet") error messages often.
I have searched around but can't find/understand what is happening and what I am supposed to do.

6. If something goes wrong while running a greenlet, I do not get the exception that points to the problem (for instance when I try to print an integer), but a similar error message as above. How can I see the "original" raised exception?

Comment: Did you find the solution to 5? I have been having the same issues.

Comment: Sorry I haven't. Can't remember how I "fixed" it. Will try to look back in to the code once I'm back at work.

Comment: Have a look at this PR https://github.com/ianepperson/telnetsrvlib/pull/2. Havn't tried this though; promises to solve the issue.